# jquery to remove text in a page

Tags: jquery, html, replace

I wish to remove the *text* "DocumentType :" from the following HTML (I am not concerned with the title or alt):

```
<tr class="ms-gb" ishdr="true" isexp="true">
  <td colspan="100" nowrap="nowrap">
    <a href="javascript:" onclick="ToggleSPGridViewGroup(this, false)" title="Expand/Collapse DocumentType : Agreement - Contract">
      <img src="/_layouts/images/minus.gif" border="0" alt="Expand/Collapse DocumentType : Agreement - Contract"/>
    </a>
    &#160;DocumentType : Agreement - Contract
  </td>
</tr>
```

In the page, I already have some JQuery that loops through the "ms-gb" classed element, but I cannot seem to dive into the appropriate elements to find "DocumentType : " in order to perform a .replace() with empty text:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".ms-gb").each(function () {
            var rowNums = $(this).nextUntil(".ms-gb").length;
            $(this).children(0).append(" (" + rowNums + ")");
            $(this).html().replace("DocumentType : ","");  //This is horribly incorrect
        });
    });
</script>
```

How can I key into this text properly in order to replace the "DocumentType : " text with an empty string?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the `html` as well:

```
var currentHtml = $(this).html();
currentHtml = currentHtml.replace("DocumentType : ","");
$(this).html(currentHtml);
```

Comment: Hmm it doesn't seem to work for me.  I believe it's because I am attempting to replace text that doesn't have its own span or div element (or rather, it is a child of a tr element that has multiple html and text elements as its children).  I could be way off here though.  Is there a method to replace TEXT instead of HTML specifically perhaps?